# mysql date conversion returns null converting certain months

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

I have this query (take a look on between dates):

```
SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT' 
FROM user_records 
WHERE date_created between (STR_TO_DATE('11/24/2020','%m/%d/%y'))  
                and (STR_TO_DATE('12/26/2021','%m/%d/%y')) 
GROUP BY user_name ;
```

The select is between dates:

**startDate:** (STR_TO_DATE(**'11/24/2020'**,'%m/%d/%y'))

**finishDate:** (STR_TO_DATE(**'12/26/2021'**,'%m/%d/%y'))

This query will return something because there are records on year **2020**

[image]

the problem is when i change the month of the finishDate, i tried with:

**finishDate:** (STR_TO_DATE(**'1**/26/2021','%m/%d/%y')) = null

**finishDate:** (STR_TO_DATE(**'01**/26/2021','%m/%d/%y')) = null

**finishDate:** (STR_TO_DATE(**'10**/26/2021','%m/%d/%y')) = null

It just makes no sense... im using mysql community 8.0.20

Comment: Why are you using `str_to_date()` with a literal date, just enter the date in the right format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: None of the last STR_TO_DATEs returns NULL. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Ditto what @forpas says, works fine here

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW WARNINGS\G`?

Comment: Do you see something like this for example... `Level: Warning Code: 1411 Message: Incorrect datetime value: '00/00/0000' for function str_to_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem only occurs in the `finsihDate` perhaps this could be helpful.

```
SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT' 
FROM user_records 
WHERE date_created between (STR_TO_DATE('11/24/2020','%m/%d/%y'))  
                and (DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('11/24/2020','%m/%d/%y'), INTERVAL 367 DAY)) 
GROUP BY user_name ;
```

Of course you should check for relevant errors or warnings in MySQL server logs, that could explain the problem for `finsihDate`.

********UPDATE SOLUTION:
for some unknown reason my db IDE shows the date with this format "$DAY/$MONTH/$YEAR" even if insert the right DATE MYSQL FORMAT ("$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY)

i got the following warnings:

[image]

And this is the final query that worked but your solution did worked as well:

```
SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT' 
FROM user_records 
WHERE date_created between '2020-11-24' AND '2021-01-24' 
GROUP BY user_name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is the date format.  Lowercase `'%y'` matches a *two digit* year.  So, only the first two characters from `2021` are used for the year -- and you have the wrong year.

But, that is not the *real* problem.  You don't need `str_to_date()`.  Just use properly formatted date literals.

Assuming that the dates are stored correctly as `date` data types, then you can simply use:

```
SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM user_records
WHERE date_created between '2020-11-24' and '2021-12-26'
GROUP BY user_name ;
```

If `date_created` is stored as a string, then fix your data model so it is either a `date` or `datetime`.  Dates should not be stored as strings.

Comment: date_created is stored as "DATE" type, but im using order 'month / day / year', that could be messing the query?